# How to display null values in IN operator for SQL with two conditions in where

Tags: sql, select

I have this query

```
select * 
from dbo.EventLogs
where EntityID = 60181615 
  and EventTypeID in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
  and NewValue = 'Received'
```

If 2 and 4 does not exist with NewValue 'Received' it shows this

[current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcEts.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KChpV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should maintain somewhere a table containing all possible `EventTypeID` values.  Sans that, we can use a CTE in place along with a left join:

```sql
WITH EventTypes AS (
    SELECT 1 AS ID UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5
)

SELECT et.ID AS EventTypeId, el.*
FROM EventTypes et
LEFT JOIN dbo.EventLogs el
    ON el.EntityID = 60181615 AND
       el.NewValue = 'Received'
WHERE
    et.ID IN (1,2,3,4,5);
```

Comment: I did create a table with all possible event type

Comment: Then replace `EventTypes` in my answer with that table.